# Creating a scrollable area for touch device without scrollbar

Tags: css

I am trying to build an horizontal scrollable area for touch devices, with just CSS, if possible. I currently have the expected setup of this:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I won't bore you with the HTML! Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: you could still make a codepen or jsfiddle. Iguess your try doesn't work:), what about with oberflow:auto. does it work, if yes there might be some to do like : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/krmel

Comment: Thanks for the help. Thought it was silly to make a fiddle, when it is for a touch device. Have tried lots of combinations of overflow properties, but cannot seem to get it to scroll. Probably best to use a plugin I think...

Comment: @JohnRobertPett: "Thought it was silly to make a fiddle, when it is for a touch device." - Why? Can't touch devices load jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The project I am working on is for a touch video wall that doesn't run a browser as such. Just thought it would be something simple that someone may have come across before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I think this is probably the best way to go:

https://github.com/ibspoof/ng-iScroll